# boost/signals2.hpp file not found in Syphon Cinder blcok

Tags: c++, boost, cinder

I'm using the Cinder block https://github.com/rezaali/Cinder-Syphon to get Syphon working with Cinder. I'm on the master branch of Cinder and pulled today to get the most up to date version. However, I'm having issues with the most up to date version of Cinder and the Syphon block. I'm getting the error

```
boost/signals2.hpp file not found
```

in the ServerDirectory.h file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by using this updated [Cinder block](https://github.com/Hperigo/Cinder-Syphon).